# Ajax function working on local but not online

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Here is my problem, I have a AJAX function which is working on my local server but don't return anything when I put it on my online server.

Here is my code :

Here the page where I call the function showEspece() :

```html
echo "<div class='tableau'>";
     echo "<table class='tableAnimal'>\n";
            echo "<thead>\n";
                echo "<td class='tdAnimal'><b> Nom </b></td>\n";
                echo "<td class='tdAnimal'><b> Nombre </b></td>\n";
            echo "</thead>\n";
      while ($row = oci_fetch_array($requete, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
          echo "<tr class='trAnimal'>\n";
           foreach ($row as $item) {
               echo "    <td class='tdAnimal'>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") . "</td>\n";
           } ?>
                        <td class='tdAnimal' onclick="showEspece(<?php echo "'";echo $row['ESPECE'];echo "'";?>, <?php echo "'";echo $categorie;echo "'";?>,this);" ><a class='lightbox'><img src='images/loupe.png'/></a></td> <?php
          echo "</tr>\n";
      }
     echo "</table>\n\n";
    echo '</div>';
```

Here is the Ajax function :

```js
function showEspece(espece, categorie, object) 
  {
    $.ajax({           
      type : 'POST',                           
      url: 'getespece.php',                  
      data: {espece: espece, categorie: categorie },                       
      dataType: 'json',                     
      success: function(data)          
      {
        alert('ok');
        var tableau = data;           
        $('#output').html(tableau); 
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is the page call by the Ajax function :

```html
<?php
     include("/includes/connexionBD.php");
         include("includes/entetepage.php");


    $requete = oci_parse($connect, "SELECT nomA, sexe, datenaissance FROM Animal WHERE categorie = '".$_POST['categorie']."' AND espece = '".$_POST['espece']."' ");
    
 oci_execute($requete);

     $table = "<table>\n";
            $table .= "<thead>\n";
                $table .= "<td><b> Nom </b></td>\n";
                $table .= "<td><b> Sexe </b></td>\n";
                $table .= "<td><b> Date naissance </b></td>\n";
            $table .= "</thead>\n";
      while ($row = oci_fetch_array($requete, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
          $table .= "<tr>\n";
           foreach ($row as $item) {
               $table .= "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") . "</td>\n";
           }
          $table .= "</tr>\n";
      }
     $table .= "</table>\n\n";

     echo json_encode($table);
?>
```

And that is what error I get on the consol :

```
VM1130:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.error (ajax.js:16)
at i (jQuery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jQuery.js:2)
at A (jQuery.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jQuery.js:4)
```

Does someone know where the problem can come from and can help me ?

Sorry fo my bad english :/

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON` - Sounds like you're getting back HTML, not JSON.  What's the actual response from the server?

Comment: I don't have any response

Comment: There’s no response *at all* from the server?  Sounds like there’s an error on the server.  Turn on error reporting, take a look at your PHP logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your JSON response is malformed, you could try getting the output JSON and put it through a linter to find where the problem actually is:

https://jsonlint.com/

I would recommend not building the HTML (your table) in PHP but building it using Javascript and injecting the data from the Ajax request into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Change php response code with the following,

```
<?php
 include("/includes/connexionBD.php");
     include("includes/entetepage.php");


$requete = oci_parse($connect, "SELECT nomA, sexe, datenaissance FROM Animal WHERE categorie = '".$_POST['categorie']."' AND espece = '".$_POST['espece']."' ");

oci_execute($requete);

    $table = "<table>\n";
        $table .= "<thead>\n";
            $table .= "<td><b> Nom </b></td>\n";
            $table .= "<td><b> Sexe </b></td>\n";
            $table .= "<td><b> Date naissance </b></td>\n";
        $table .= "</thead>\n";
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($requete, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            $table .= "<tr>\n";
                foreach ($row as $item) {
                    $table .= "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") . "</td>\n";
                }
            $table .= "</tr>\n";
        }
    $table .= "</table>\n\n";

    echo json_encode(array("table"=>$table, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
?>
```

change ajax code with the following

```
function showEspece(espece, categorie, object) 
{
    $.ajax({           
        type : 'POST',                           
        url: 'getespece.php',                  
        data: {espece: espece, categorie: categorie },                       
        dataType: 'json',                     
        success: function(data)          
        {
            alert('ok');
            var tbl = $.parseJSON(data);
            var tableau = tbl.table;
            console.log(tableau);           
            $('#output').html(tableau); 
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still don't working. But I don't have any error in the consol